# Outer addition with Eigen

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I am attempting to translate the following python function into C++:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import blas
def scaled_dist(a, b, ls):
    al = a/ls
    bl = b/ls
    tmp1 = np.sum(al**2, axis=1)
    tmp2 = np.sum(bl**2, axis=1)
    tmp3 = np.add.outer(tmp1, tmp2, order='F')
    tau = blas.dgemm(a=al, b=bl, alpha=-2.0, c=tmp3, beta=1, trans_b=1)
    np.clip(tau, 0, np.inf, out=tau)
    return tau
```

However I have hit a stumbling block with the line:

```py
tmp3 = np.add.outer(tmp1, tmp2)
```

My c++ code compiles but encounters a runtime error when executed. The code (up to that line) is:

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd test2(const Eigen::MatrixXd &x1, const Eigen::MatrixXd &x2,const Eigen::VectorXd &vec)
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd r = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(x1.rows(), x2.rows());
  Eigen::MatrixXd al = x1.array().rowwise() / vec.transpose().array();
  Eigen::VectorXd tmp1 = al.array().square().rowwise().sum();

  Eigen::MatrixXd bl = x2.array().rowwise() / vec.transpose().array(); 
  Eigen::VectorXd tmp2 = bl.array().square().rowwise().sum();

  r = tmp1.transpose().array() + tmp2.array();
  return r;
}
```

I am able to make sense of the runtime error, which is (I believe) an assertion error, complaining that the left and right hand sides of the addition expression do not match in size. My approach was motivated by the fact that `tmp1.transpose() * tmp2` *does* appear to produce the expected result.

**My question is as follows:**

Given two vectors, `vec1` and `vec2`, what is the idiomatic way using Eigen of achieving the same functionality as `numpy.add.outer(vec1, vec2)`, namely an "outer" addition whereby a matrix is obtained by adding the (broadcast) rows of one vector to the (broadcast) columns of the other? i.e., if

```
vec1 = [1,2,3]
vec2 = [3,4,5]
```

then

```
outer_add(vec1, vec2) = 
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replicate for that, e.g.:

```
Vector3f v1(1,2,3), v2(3,4,5);
MatrixXf r = v1.rowwise().replicate(v2.size())
           + v2.transpose().colwise().replicate(v1.size());
```